# Unable to access internet in Ubuntu on a virtual machine with Windows host

Tags: firefox, mac, proxy, network-bridge

I have installed Ubuntu in a VirtualBox and tried all the possible ways mentioned online to access internet but failed. But using the bridge option I feel there is a connection between them because Firefox is able to open only one link that is the below

```
https://teamforge.*****
```

one provided by our company. So it looks like there is a problem with the proxy in Firefox but I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does your company network use a proxy server by any chance?

Comment: Please dit your question and describe which options you tried and what results.

Comment: I made it work myself.I use two adapters bridge and NAT. Need to make sure both are connected which will be displayed by holding the mouse on the computer icon thing. And click on the edit connections from the network manager list and delete all the other connections.Should work.

Comment: And very imp should enable all the FTTP,HTTP,HTTPS services in the vitual box found in control panel options.